# `rememberSaveable` but in-memory instead of on-disk (like `viewModel()`)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, is there something like `rememberSaveable` but does not save to disk so it works like `viewModel()`? Currently I'm having this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var initialized: Boolean = false

    var needsToBeInitialized = mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null)
}

@Composable
func HelloWorld() {
    val model: MyViewModel = viewModel()

    // this needs to survive device rotation
    var needsToBeInitialized by model.needsToBeInitialized

    if (!model.initialized) {
        model.needsToBeInitialized.value = getBooleanOrNullSomehow()

        model.initialized = true
    }
}
```

With `rememberSaveable` it's just a nice one-liner, so I was thinking if it was possible to achieve something like `viewModel()` in just a one line as well, so it stores data in memory instead.

Comment: How is what you’re describing any different than just `remember { }`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 OP wants the stored value to survive configuration changes. A value returned by a `remember` call (that is not backed by a view model) only survives recompositions.

Comment: There is no other built-in function that would store a value that survives a configuration change (other than `rememberSaveable` and `viewModel`). But it is possible to write a custom function that would do what you want behind the scenes (i.e. store the value in memory). Then you could use your custom function as a one-liner in your codebase. Keep in mind that would be less powerful than `rememberSaveable` as it would not survive system-initiated process death. Are you ok with that?

Comment: I think Google recommends disabling config change activity restarts in the manifest when using Compose. But I don’t remember where I saw that. Might just be a tweet from a Google engineer.

Comment: Yep, I don't want it to survive system-initiated process death.

Comment: @Tenfour04 According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes `Some configuration changes always cause the activity to restart. You can't disable them. For example, you can't disable the dynamic colors change introduced in API 32. More configuration changes could behave similarly in the future.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you are describing by creating a custom remember function that is using a "generic" ViewModel class that keeps any state assigned to it in memory.

The "generic" ViewModel and the custom remember function (I called it `rememberInMemory`)

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisallowComposableCalls
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

/**
 * A generic [ViewModel] class that will keep any state assigned to it in memory.
 */
class StateMapViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val states: MutableMap<String, Pair<Array<out Any?>, Any?>> = mutableMapOf()
}

/**
 * Remember the value produced by [init].
 *
 * It behaves similarly to [remember], but the stored value will survive configuration changes
 * (for example when the screen is rotated in the Android application).
 * The value will not survive process recreation/death.
 *
 * @param dataKey A string to be used as a key for the saved value.
 * @param inputs A set of inputs such that, when any of them have changed, will cause the state to
 * reset and [init] to be rerun
 * @param init A factory function to create the initial value of this state
 * @return The state that is stored in memory.
 */
@Composable
inline fun <reified T> rememberInMemory(
    dataKey: String,
    vararg inputs: Any?,
    crossinline init: @DisallowComposableCalls () -> T,
): T {
    val vm: StateMapViewModel = viewModel()
    return remember(*inputs) {
        val value = vm.states[dataKey]
            ?.takeIf { it.first.contentEquals(inputs) }
            ?: Pair(inputs, init()).also {
                vm.states[dataKey] = it
            }
        value.second as T
    }
}
```

When calling `rememberInMemory` a string has to be provided as the `dataKey` argument. This key will be used to get the current stored value. If the given `dataKey` does not have a stored value yet, the `init` lambda will be called to obtain the initial value, which will be stored and returned. The `inputs` are optional variable length arguments and when any of them have changed it will cause the `init` lambda to be called again to obtain the new value, which will be stored and returned.

The scope of the data being kept in memory will be the same as the default `ViewModel` scope, which means this function will work the same as a `ViewModel` approach would.

When using navigation the `StateMapViewModel` will be scoped to each `NavBackStackEntry`. This means that every time when navigating to a new destination, a new `StateMapViewModel` instance will be created and when navigating back or up, the existing `StateMapViewModel` instance from the previous `NavBackStackEntry` will be used. So even with navigation this approach will work the same as would using a `ViewModel` directly.

If you are using any dependency injection frameworks replace the `viewModel()` call inside the `rememberInMemory` function with the correct `viewModel()`/`getViewModel()` call from the framework.

---

Below is a demo app showing how this works with data scoped to 3 different navigation destinations and some data scoped to their parent.

Since the demo is using Compose Navigation, you have to add a dependency to your `app/build.gradle` to try the demo.

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Demo()
        }
    }
}
```

Demo.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.KeyboardArrowDown
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.KeyboardArrowUp
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Divider
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Demo() {
    @Composable
    fun Surface(content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Counter(text: String, counterState: MutableState<Int>) {
        var counter by counterState
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            val modifier = Modifier
                .padding(2.dp)
                .background(
                    color = Color.Unspecified,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(100)
                )
            val colors = IconButtonDefaults.iconButtonColors(
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
            )
            IconButton(onClick = { counter-- }, modifier, colors = colors) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown, contentDescription = "Decrement")
            }
            IconButton(onClick = { counter++ }, modifier, colors = colors) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp, contentDescription = "Increment")
            }
            Text(text = "$text: $counter")
        }
    }

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    var countdown by rememberInMemory("Countdown") { mutableStateOf(0) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            countdown = 9
            while (countdown > 0) {
                delay(1000)
                countdown--
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    val parentCounter = rememberInMemory("Counter", countdown > 0) { mutableStateOf(0) }

    var previousCounter by rememberInMemory("Previous Counter") {
        mutableStateOf(parentCounter)
    }

    Column {
        Surface {
            Text("Countdown: $countdown seconds until parent counter resets")

            Counter("Parent counter", parentCounter)

            Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)) {
                val route = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination?.route

                Button(onClick = { navController.navigateUp() }, enabled = route != "countersA") {
                    Text(text = "Go back")
                }

                when (route) {
                    "countersA" -> Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("countersB") }) {
                        Text(text = "Show Counters B")
                    }
                    "countersB" -> Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("countersC") }) {
                        Text(text = "Show Counters C")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Divider(thickness = Dp.Hairline)

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "countersA") {
            composable("countersA") {
                Surface {
                    val counterA = rememberInMemory("Counter") { mutableStateOf(-1) }
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        previousCounter = counterA
                    }

                    Counter("Counter A", counterA)

                    Counter("Parent Counter", parentCounter)
                }
            }
            composable("countersB") {
                Surface {
                    val counterB = rememberInMemory("Counter") { mutableStateOf(-2) }
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        previousCounter = counterB
                    }

                    Counter("Counter B", counterB)

                    Counter("Previous Counter", rememberInMemory("Previous Counter") { previousCounter })

                    Counter("Parent Counter", parentCounter)
                }
            }
            composable("countersC") {
                Surface {
                    val counterC = rememberInMemory("Counter") { mutableStateOf(-3) }
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        previousCounter = counterC
                    }

                    Counter("Counter C", counterC)

                    Counter("Previous Counter", rememberInMemory("Previous Counter") { previousCounter })

                    Counter("Parent Counter", parentCounter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `takeIf` unnecessary? When configuration changes `inputs` don't change I think.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak `takeIf` is necessary for when `inputs` change, in the sense that if you remove it, then even when `inputs` change normally (not due to a configuration change), the state map will keep returning the old state. In the demo example above the counter reset use-case stops working.

Comment: That makes sense as the data is stored in the map immediately. Perhaps `DisposableEffect` would fix this, since the data would be saved only when the composition gets recreated, rerenders would use the `remember`ed value.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved [@Ma3x's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76124261/5189849). This uses [`DisposableEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#disposableeffect) as in [`rememberSaveable`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/runtime/runtime-saveable/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/RememberSaveable.kt;l=66?q=rememberSaveable&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport:compose%2F), so `dataKey` should be unnecessary now.

```
package com.example.stackoverflow

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisallowComposableCalls
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.currentCompositeKeyHash
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberUpdatedState
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

/**
 * A generic [ViewModel] class that will keep any state assigned to it in memory.
 */
class StateMapViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val states: MutableMap<Int, ArrayDeque<Any>> = mutableMapOf()
}

/**
 * Remember the value produced by [init].
 *
 * It behaves similarly to [remember], but the stored value will survive configuration changes
 * (for example when the screen is rotated in the Android application).
 * The value will not survive process recreation.
 *
 * @param inputs A set of inputs such that, when any of them have changed, will cause the state to
 * reset and [init] to be rerun
 * @param init A factory function to create the initial value of this state
 */
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : Any> rememberInMemory(
    vararg inputs: Any?,
    crossinline init: @DisallowComposableCalls () -> T,
): T {
    val vm: StateMapViewModel = viewModel()

    val key = currentCompositeKeyHash

    val value = remember(*inputs) {
        val states = vm.states[key] ?: ArrayDeque<Any>().also { vm.states[key] = it }

        states.removeFirstOrNull() as T? ?: init()
    }

    val valueState = rememberUpdatedState(value)

    DisposableEffect(key) {
        onDispose {
            vm.states[key]?.addFirst(valueState.value)
        }
    }

    return value
}
```

Comment: This is the first approach that I have tried, but since `currentCompositeKeyHash` returns a value that is "likely to be unique, but is not guaranteed unique" this approach would require a more complex implementation where the value inside the map is a list of states and where you then manage the correct insertion and retrieval order. Otherwise this approach does not work for a general use-case (in the demo in my answer it crashes the runtime, because a state of a different type is saved under the key of a previous state).

Comment: @Ma3x You're right! I have revised my answer to use `DisposableEffect` instead so it does not depend on `currentCompositeKeyHash`. It seems to work, could you check please?

Comment: *(I meant alongside `currentCompositeKeyHash`)